# How NOT to return last expression's value from a Kotlin block?

Tags: kotlin

I have a method that returns nothing. Inside it, there's a try-catch block:

```
override fun sendResourceCreationRequest(...) {
    try {
        val requestEntity = ...
        restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity)
    } catch (e: RestClientException) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Because the value of the last expression in a try block is returned implicitly, I get this compiler error:

```
Type mismatch.
Required: Nothing
Found: ResponseEntity<???>
```

I can assign the value to a variable and the error goes away:

```
val response: ResponseEntity<Unit> = restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity)
```

But now I have an unused variable which I (and lint) don't like. What's the best way to handle this?

---

**Edit**

The error went away when I specified the response type explicitly:

```
restTemplate.exchange<Unit>(requestEntity)
```

Perhaps something to do with [exchange](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-web/src/main/kotlin/org/springframework/web/client/RestOperationsExtensions.kt#L289) being an inline reified function or something?

> ```
> @Throws(RestClientException::class)
> inline fun <reified T> RestOperations.exchange(requestEntity: RequestEntity<*>): ResponseEntity<T> =
>       exchange(requestEntity, object : ParameterizedTypeReference<T>() {})
> ```

Comment: I tried reproducing it but I don't an error. [This](https://pl.kotl.in/6Ux8IpMp1) is was I tried.

Comment: @ArpitShukla Thanks for trying. Please see my edit, which would explain why your example works.

Comment: What is ParameterizedTypeReference here? And can u show the function signature of the other exchange function that you are calling?

Comment: @ArpitShukla `exchange` is from spring framework defined [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-web/src/main/kotlin/org/springframework/web/client/RestOperationsExtensions.kt#L289), and the type is the response payload type of the REST call

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I'm not 100% sure what is going on here, but I think you misinterpreted this case. This error has nothing to do with the return type of `sendResourceCreationRequest()`. Assuming the sample is (almost) complete, this function does not return `Nothing`, but `Unit`, so the error message does not make too much sense. Also, last expression is implicitly returned only in lambdas, but not in regular functions. Value of `restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity)` expression in this sample is not really returned, but simply ignored.

The problem is different. `exchange()` is parameterized and it requires to provide its `T`, so it could work properly. Both of these code fragments provide `T`:

```kotlin
restTemplate.exchange<Unit>(requestEntity)
val response: ResponseEntity<Unit> = restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity)
```

However, in your original code (`restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity)`) `T` is unknown.

Still, I'm not sure why you get error about `Nothing` and not that `T` can't be inferred. It may be somehow related to contents of inner `exchange()` function.

But anyway, the direct answer to your question is that you should use `exchange<Unit>()`. I'm just not sure if this will work for you as the REST framework may try to interpret the response as `Unit` which probably won't work. I don't know what is the REST library you use and what is your case exactly, but if you just need to ignore the response and if `Unit` doesn't work, you can try `exchange<String>()`. In many REST frameworks that means: "don't process the response body, return it as it is".

Comment: I'm using Spring Boot RestTemplate's exchange (link is in the edit section of the question). You're right that it returns `Unit`. But I need to understand why the whole enclosing try-catch block becomes red with that error about `Nothing`.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler states the error as `Nothing` has to be returned to the method `sendResourceCreationRequest()`, which means the signature of the method has to be like this:

```kotlin
abstract fun sendResourceCreationRequest(): Nothing
```

Check the definition of `Nothing` from below:

```kotlin
/**
 * Nothing has no instances.
 * You can use Nothing to represent "a value that never exists":
 * for example,
 * if a function has the return type of Nothing,
 * it means that it never returns (always throws an exception).
 */
public class Nothing private constructor()
```

Since `sendResourceCreationRequest()` has `Nothing` as return-type, this method will have to halt the further executions by throwing an Exception.

From the use-case point of view, if this is not the intended behaviour of the method, just remove the return type `Nothing` and replace it with `Unit`.

```kotlin
abstract fun sendResourceCreationRequest(): Unit // Explicit way of saying method won't return anything.

// OR

abstract fun sendResourceCreationRequest() // Implicit way of saying method won't return anything.
```